# How to generate 100 random numbers and checking each one for primality?

Tags: javascript

Write a Boolean function named `isPrime` which takes an integer as an argument and returns true if the argument is a prime number of false otherwise. Generate 100 random numbers and display the results of checking each one for primality.

This is supposed to output the random numbers that are prime (after the true or false check) but I am getting the results of 2 sets of numbers in order.

Here is my code:

```
var arr = []

while(arr.length < 100){
    var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)
    var found=false;

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]==randomnumber){found=true;break}
    }
    if(!found)arr[arr.length]=randomnumber;
}

    console.log(arr);

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if(isPrime(i)) console.log(i);
}

function isPrime(num) {
    if(num < 2) return false;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: All questions in this forum are getting down to more & more imbecile levels.

Comment: @ВидулПетров yes that's true, they are a low quality question and answer. What should we do? Should I delete my own answer and flag to close question?

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia Add subcategories.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check for primality of `arr[i]` instead of `i`:

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if(isPrime(arr[i])) console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function isPrime(value) {
for(var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
    if(value % i === 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
return value > 1;
```

}

```
function myFunction() {
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

$('#demo').append('<div>'+i+'*****'+isPrime(i)+'</div>');

}
```

}

try it in an html page and dont forget to add jquery

Answer (score 0):

The below code part, you are trying to check the numbers from 0 to 100

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if(isPrime(i)) console.log(i);
}
```

But you should check the arr array one by one

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if(isPrime(arr[i])) console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an object to store the numbers let's you avoid the loop to check for duplicates and moving the check for isPrime () let's you skip the second loop. (Your issue was, as @Andrea pointed out, not passing arr [i] to isPrime)

```
var myRandObj = {};
var randomNumber = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    do {
        randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
    } while (typeof myRandObj[randomNumber] !== 'undefined');
    myRandObj[randomNumber] = 0;

    if (isPrime (randomNumber))
        console.log (randomNumber);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

console.log(arr) is printing the entire array to the console. Remove that line to debug further.

```
var arr = []

for(x = 0; x < 100; x++){
    arr[x] = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)
    }

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if(isPrime(arr[i])) console.log(arr[i]);
}

function isPrime(num) {
    if(num < 2) return false;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When I remove that, it prints the prime numbers but they are arranged in order even thought I have the random property :(